# Nested For loops with python and csv

Tags: python, loops, csv

I am having issues coding a nested for loop with `csv` objects in python. I want to parse both `csv` files and compare parts of them. Therefore I coded the nested loop below. 
What I expect is that the python parses the inner loop for the first item of the outer loop and then for the second item of the outer loop he parses again the inner loop and so on.
Whats happening is,  the inner loop gets parsed and then the outer loop gets passed without even entering the inner loop again.

When using non `csv` objects like `num_list = [1, 2, 3]` this works like expected.

Thanks.

```
import csv

csvfile = open('/Users/rene/Downloads/Test/Export.csv', newline='', encoding='windows-1252')
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', delimiter=';')

csvfile1 = open('/Users/rene/Downloads/Test/Transfer.csv', newline='', encoding='windows-1252')
spamreader1 = csv.reader(csvfile1, dialect='excel', delimiter=';')

for row in spamreader:
    print("1row:"+row[1])
    for row1 in spamreader1:
        print("2row:"+row[1])
        print("2row1:"+row1[0])

csvfile.close()
csvfile1.close()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `csv.reader` objects are iterators that get exhausted when they are consumed. Hence, `spamreader1` is already empty after the first iteration of the outer loop.

Simply turn `spamreader1`, which you iterate in the inner loop, into a `list` so you can iterate it multiple times:

```
# ...
# collect all rows in a list
spamreader1 = list(csv.reader(csvfile1, dialect='excel', delimiter=';'))

for row in spamreader:
    # ...
    for row1 in spamreader1:
        # now this will work as you expect
```